# spring-boot-starter-artemis with AMQP protocol

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, activemq-artemis

I was following the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-artemis guide.

With Core protocol with JMS, app is able to send message to Artemis broker.

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=<broker host>
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=<password>
```

When I switched to AMQP protocol with 5672 port, I am getting below error.

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=<broker host>
spring.artemis.port=5672
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.password=<password>
```

```
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:712) ~[artemis-core-client-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.12.0.jar:2.12.0]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

what changes I have to make along to enable transition over AMQP protocol in my spring boot app? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the AMQP protocol you'd need to somehow force Spring to use the [Qpid JMS](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/) client implementation rather than ActiveMQ Artemis' core JMS client implementation, but I don't believe that is possible.